# Redirect in Interceptor when not logged

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ejb, interceptor

Im trying to use @aroundInvoke in my interceptor, checking some validationX to proceed with the execution of the method or else REDIRECT the user to a specific JSF page.

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object myInterceptor(InvocationContext invocation) throws Exception {
        if(validationX){//it passes the validation so proceed
            return invocation.proceed();    
        }else{//it doesnt passes the validation so go to 
            //DO SOMETHING TO REDIRECT TO SPECIFIC JSF
        }

    }
```

I've tried:

- returning String with "JSF?faces-redirect=true" ----- I get converting error(String to whatever the metod should return).
- FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("/JSF.jsf");  ----- I get nullPointerException with getCurrentInstance method.
- FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/JSF.jsf"); -------The same NullPointerException.

  - Using HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse to generate a response but I get NullPointer Exception.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java EE interceptor isn't intented for that. It's intented to be used to decide whether to proceed the invocation of the current CDI/EJB bean method or not (and if necessary throw an exception to abort it), and/or to control/manipulate its return value. It's not intented to act as a JSF controller. For that a normal JSF managed bean should be used instead.

Or, if this concerns an exceptional circumstance, then you should just throw a specific exception and register an `<error-page>` in `web.xml` on exactly that exception type. If you can hook on specific URLs rather than specific method invocations, another way would be to perform the job in a simple [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) instead.

As the concrete functional requirement for which you [incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) thought that this would be the right solution is not clear from the question, a more detailed answer can't be given.

Comment: The solution was intended to protect certain methods of certain EJB, servlet filter is already up and running protecting carpets and urls being used. The only way to protect methods getting called is this way, going to wait to another answer; if there isnt one I'll give you my thumbs up.

Comment: Throw a specific runtime exception and configure an `<error-page>` for that.

Comment: Trying that solution I come across another complication; surely thats the right answer but my custom exception gets wrap around EJBException or ServletException, any idea to throw it as a standalone to be capturable within the errorpage?

Comment: `ServletException` is not a problem. The container implicitly unwraps it. `EJBException` can be unwrapped and rethrown as `new ServletException(e.getCause())` using a servlet filter with a `try-catch` on `EJBException` around `FilterChain#doFilter()` call.

Comment: Well after all Thanx for all the help, doing it just like you suggested at the end I parsed the Exception/Throwable that the try return to me (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867942/determine-the-root-exception) and finally find out if it was my custom Exception. Again Thanx!